# gitignore does not ignore folder

Tags: git, gitignore

In the root of my project I have a `foo` folder. Inside the `foo` folder I have a `bar` folder. I would like to ignore all changes to all files inside my `bar` folder. I have this in my `gitignore`:

```
/foo/bar
```

The folder is checked: it exists and it has the files to be ignored. `gitignore` is `commit`ted. However, I have a file where I make a moification and is inside my `bar` folder. When I type

```
git status
```

inside my `git bash` I see the file which should have been ignored. What could be the reason and how can I successfully ignore all files inside my bar folder?

Note, that the files were previously ignored with the same line, but I had to temporarily remove that line to `commit` something on the server. After the `commit`, I put back the line into the `gitignore`. This was a while ago, but now I have observed that the files will be in `git status`. I would expect to be able to modify the ignored files without they appearing in the `git status`.

Comment: In the future, you don't need to modify your ignores to add something ignored. `git add -f ignored-file` will add a file even if it's in your ignores.

Comment: What does `git status foo/bar/file-that-should-be-ignored` give?

Comment: The file which should be ignored if any change occured. I am obviously missing something, but according to my knowledge the list of git status should be empty in that case provided that /foo/bar is present in .gitignore

Comment: It sounds like that file is actually being tracked by Git. It must have been added to the repository at some point. You can see its history with `git log foo/bar/file-that-should-be-ignored`. If it shouldn't be part of the repository you should remove it with `git rm --cached foo/bar/file-that-should-be-ignored` and then commit as suggested by Reck below (though I would just do it on the file, not the whole folder). This will (a) remove the file from Git, (b) *keep the file* in your local copy, and (c) cause the file to be deleted when others `fetch` or `pull` the new commit.

Comment: I want to remove all files in the folder from git, but of course, I want to keep them. The folder contains local settings for development environments, therefore the content of the whole folder should be ignored by git

Comment: Then `git rm --cached` is likely correct. Just bear in mind that every other copy will lose those files when they integrate the commit; you'll need to be careful when merging it in.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, it must be done with care. But if local settings are not proper, the project will not work on the local machine, so we will know whenever careless copy occured.

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/274502

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 680, accepted):

I'm guessing this folder has been checked into git before?

Run `git rm -r --cached <folder>` and check again.

Comment: This will completely remove the folder from the (current version of the) repo. OP wants the folder to be there, but new changes should not be tracked

Comment: Unfortunately I have to remove the accept. This solution removed the remote versions of the files when pushed. I want to set up gitignore to ignore all files of a folder, not to remove it from remote. Is that possible? I have reverted the solution.

Comment: I want the remote server to keep its version of the files

Comment: `git update-index --assume-unchanged <folder>` perhaps?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index - it stops git from checking if there are any modifications made in that path. Note that it will only do this on YOUR machine. So if you have colleagues who need this ignored as well, this is not the right approach.

Comment: Well then, it seems this is not the right approach. If the path is in gitignore, is it in a cache which will eventually be emptied?

Comment: @Lajos shouldn't you just have fixed his bug instead of adding this confusing "edit" comment there?

Comment: @Cawas, as this site is about knowledge sharing, the answer is: no. It is misleading to accept an answer which contains a bug. That -r is not optional.

Comment: @LajosArpad that's what I mean. Fix the bug in the edition.

Comment: This answer, which is older than a year, edited more than a year ago was upvoted as it is. So it was helpful for users in its current form.

Comment: I see this answer has 135 -1=134 votes but it does not answer the OP question. I am in the same dilemma. I have added .vs/ in my .git/.gitignore file but the .vs folder is always shown in git status command which is annoying.

Comment: I had been banging my head against the wall for two days because of this lol. How did i forget about caching. I though it was intellij :(

Comment: This worked for me. I would like to add that I needed to restart VS code to see the folder marked in gray in the explorer.

Comment: This didn't work. It doesn't seem like my folder has been already pushed. I get the following error "fatal: pathspec 'unpackaged' did not match any files".

Comment: I'm getting `fatal: <folder>: '<folder>' is outside repository`

Comment: @BenAlan Try to enter full path to that folder. I have had the same situation like you.

Comment: Running the command told me, that my files were already staged: so thats why i couldn't ignore the folder. After unstaging the files, the folder was ignored.

Answer (score 117):

For me, the accepted answer was part of the solution, not the entire solution. Maybe, the other steps that I'm about to post were obvious, but I missed them first. Here's the steps I took to ensure my `.gitignore` file ignored the folder I wanted it to ignore:

1. Commit any changes that you need to fix/change.
2. Run this command: `git rm -r --cached .` (which removes everything from the git index in order to refresh your git repository)
3. Then run this command: `git add .` (to add everything back to the repo)
4. Finally, commit these changes using `git commit -m ".gitignore Fixed"`

You can find the link to the article from where I found the solution [here](https://digitizor.com/gitignore-not-ignoring-files-how-to-fix/).

Comment: This is not a viable solution based on the original question. @lagos-arpad specifically asked about a subdirectory and not the entire project. Your solution removes everything from the root level of the git repository and this is not a recommended approach to deal with this problem.

Comment: Even if it's only a subdirectory , this solution worked for me as I was dealing with only one file. Can you please elaborate why it's not recommended?

Comment: What you were dealing with is immaterial. This is not the answer to the question and is potentially dangerous as the other answer has pointed out. This removes stuff on the remote repo which you don't necessarily want.

Comment: this worked exactly as i needed it to work. weirdly the latest commit showed the previous commits and not ".gitignore Fixed"! But again, my issue was solved

Comment: @justinhartman , you can specify your folder name by replacing . with <folder>

Answer (score 26):

## This solved it

I had done `echo node_modules >> .gitignore` and it didn't work.

the windows terminal from saves the file in `UCS-2 LE BOM` and git doesn't seem to accept that.

I opened the file with `Notepad` and saved with `UTF-8` encoding

[image: notepad save utf-8 encoding]

**It Works now.**

I think they need to fix this since `echo "filetoignore" >> .gitignore` actually seems a handy thing to do

Comment: I had the same issue when redirecting Powershell's output to gitignore. 
E.g. `Get-ChildItem . -Filter *.csv -recurse >> .gitignore` did not work until I changed the encoding to UTF-8. And yes, I know ignoring all csv files can be achieved directly via .gitignore: This was just meant as an example ;)

Answer (score 19):

I was having this issue and I realized git was actually ignoring the files/folders correctly, but my code editor (Visual Studio Code) was just buggy and not "greying them out" properly in the UI sidebar. I restarted VSCode and they were greyed out as expected.

Comment: Same here: VS Code v1.30.2 (user)

Comment: Same for me. Thank you very much for this solution! I was wondering why my .gitignore wasn't working until I tried restarting VS Code.I'm on Visual Studio Code v1.44.2.

Answer (score 11):

As an addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410260/11312528)

```
git rm -r --cached /foo/bar/
git status
```

When i do that, the terminal shows a bunch of `rm` for files in that directory. So to prevent another commit that might unnecessarily affect remote, I i did:

```
git reset HEAD *
git status
```

After that, it said nothing to commit and when i modify files inside `/foo/bar/` and do a `git status` i still get `nothing to commit`.

Comment: This just returns me to where I started (the problem)

Answer (score 7):

I created the .gitignore in powershell using `echo "build" > .gitignore`. This created a file with UTF-16LE encoding. Git did not recognize the contents of the file and continued to show the `build` folder as untracked. I deleted the file and recreated it in the geany text editor (UTF-8) and git now ignores the `build` folder. A short search re-inforces that that git doesn't like UTF-16.

Comment: I figured this out finally, before I saw your answer. Then I scrolled through the rest of the questions expecting to see someone commenting / answering on this scenario :P

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time it's an encoding issue. So you may delete the .gitignore file and create it again.

EDIT:

Proof:

1. Create a folder called test-gitignore
2. Go to that folder and initialize a git repo: `git init`
3. Create a .env file and add anything there
4. Now you want to ignore that .env file, so what you should do is create a `.gitignore` file in the same directory having a content: `.env`. But the way you create that .gitignore file is important. If you create it using powershell's echo: "echo >> .gitignore", your .env will not be ignored, because git expects a utf-8 encoded .gitignore file.
   `In PowerShell, the default encoding used by the echo command for writing text to a file is Unicode (UTF-16LE). This means that when you use the echo command to append text to a file using >>, the text will be written in UTF-16LE encoding.`

This is why it's important to create the file using vscode, or any tool ensure a utf-8 encoding.

Comment: No, this issue was caused by the fact that some files inside the folder were already versioned.

Comment: That's another story. But if you haven't versioned any of these files inside the folder, then that's most probably then answer (I've been there).

Comment: That's an interesting point. In the context of this question, it was definitely an already versioned file in that folder. But I'm still happy to upvote your answer if you provide reproduction steps for the phenomenon you have described above.