# gitignore not ignoring files/folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to working with git properly but some issue are occur.On GitStatus, there files shown modified.

```
 modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/.gitignore
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/.htaccess.sample
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/_bootstrap.php
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/_data/lorem_ipsum.txt
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/_suite/WYSIWYGDisabledSuite.xml
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/_suite/suite.xml.sample
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductCatalogSearch/LICENSE.txt
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductCatalogSearch/LICENSE_AFL.txt
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductCatalogSearch/README.md
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductCatalogSearch/Test/EndToEndB2CGuestUserTest.xml
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductCatalogSearch/Test/EndToEndB2CLoggedInUserTest.xml
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductWishlist/ActionGroup/StorefrontCustomerWishlistActionGroup.xml
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductWishlist/LICENSE.txt
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductWishlist/LICENSE_AFL.txt
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductWishlist/README.md
    modified:   dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/ConfigurableProductWishlist/Test/EndToEndB2CLoggedInUserTest.xml
    modified:   dev/tests/api-functional/.gitignore
```

Here my ignore file:

```
/dev/*   
/dev/test/*
```

I already studied many articles but I can't get a soluton.
Reference Article:[gitignore does not ignore folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410208/gitignore-does-not-ignore-folder)

I try this command :`git rm -r --cached`.Now, This show the following files as deleted.So when i run `git add.` & `git push origin master` it delete from master or not?

Answer (score 1):

Don't run `git add` after removing. Simply commit the `git rm` command and it'll remove it from the `index`. If you run `git add` before commiting, it'll add the staged removals back into the `index`.

Run the following commands to remove the files from the `index` and maintain the local files.

```
git rm --cached -r dev/tests
git commit -m "Removed dev tests"
git push origin master
```

Within the root of the project, make sure you have a `.gitignore` with the following in

```
dev/tests/*
```