# How to add Django env folder into .gitignore?

Tags: python, django, git

What would I write in my .gitignore file to make it so the CIS440_Env folder is ignored?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repositories-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the name of the folder as a new line in your .gitignore:

`CIS440_Env/`

Comment: i do that but it doesn't work, is it because the folder was already committed once to the repo?

Comment: It's still detected as a change ? Have you refreshed git ?

Comment: yes, my .gitignore has the line CIS440_Env/ in my repo but the folder is still there. I have also tried CIS440_Project/CIS440_Env/

Comment: Run `git rm -r --cached <folder>` in a cmd and check again.

Comment: fatal: pathspec 'CIS440_Env' did not match any files. and i also tried with the name CIS440_Env/

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944428/13964753 ... If that does not work, then if you just set up your git repo maybe reinitialize it with folder in gitignore...